# Update XML file from a XML Template

Tags: c#, c++, xml

I have two xml file one being called config.xml and configtemplate.xml. What I am trying to do is add lines from the configtemplate.xml to the config.xml file.

```
config.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
 <Database>
    <DataType>1</DataType>
    <ServerName>192.168.50.80</ServerName>
  // add information here supplied by the configtemplate.xml
 </Database>

 <Services>
    <Wash>1</Wash>
  // add information here supplied by the configtemplate.xml
 </Services>

 <Options>
    <TaxRate>8.125</TaxRate>
    <AskForZipcode>0</AskForZipcode>
 // add information here supplied by the configtemplate.xml
 </Options>
```

What I need is for it to get all the data from configtemplate.xml and add it to the config file without it overriding and value that are in their.

Also the value in configtemplate.xml are going to be different then what they might have.

```
configtemplate.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
 <Database>
    <DataType>1</DataType>
    <ServerName>192.168.50.80</ServerName>
  // add all lines below to config.xml
    <DatabaseName>TestDB</DatabaseName>
 </Database>

 <Services>
    <Wash>1</Wash>
  // add all lines below to config.xmlxml
    <Greeter>0</Greeter>
 </Services>

 <Options>
    <TaxRate>8.125</TaxRate>
    <AskForZipcode>0</AskForZipcode>
 // add all lines below to config.xml
    <AutoSave>1</AutoSave>
 </Options>
```

I am hoping I am explaining by self correctly and Thank you

Comment: Are you trying to do this in C++ or C#?

Comment: C# is my preferred way but I am at the point where I don't care lol

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you can use `ImportNode` to add data from one xml to another.

Something like this.

```
XmlDocument doc1 = new XmlDocument();
doc1.Load("config.xml");
XmlDocument doc2 = new XmlDocument();
doc2.Load("configtemplate.xml");
XmlNode doc1root, doc2root, importNode;

doc1root = doc1.DocumentElement;
doc2root = doc2.DocumentElement;

foreach(XmlNode node in doc2root.ChildNodes)
{
    importNode = doc1root.OwnerDocument.ImportNode(node, true);
    doc1root.AppendChild(importNode);
}
```

This way it import `<Database>`, `<Services>`, `<Options>` from **configtemplate.xml** into **config.xml** under `<config>`

In your case, you will need to know the tag you want to import from and to, which is not specified in your example.

**Explanation:**

`doc1root` is the root tag of **config.xml**, which is `<config>`

`doc2root` is the root tag of **configtemplate.xml**, which is `<config>`

in the `foreach` loop, you are looping through each child node of `doc2root` (which are `<Database>`, `<Services>`, and `<Options>`), and adding each child node to be a child of `doc1root`

With the above code what you will get is a new **config.xml** that looks like this.

```
<config>
 <Database>
    <DataType>1</DataType>
    <ServerName>192.168.50.80</ServerName>
    // add information here supplied by the configtemplate.xml
 </Database>

 <Services>
    <Wash>1</Wash>
    // add information here supplied by the configtemplate.xml
 </Services>

 <Options>
   <TaxRate>8.125</TaxRate>
   <AskForZipcode>0</AskForZipcode>
   // add information here supplied by the configtemplate.xml
 </Options>

 //below are from configtemplate.xml
 <Database>
    <DataType>1</DataType>
    <ServerName>192.168.50.80</ServerName>
    // add all lines below to config.xml
    <DatabaseName>TestDB</DatabaseName>
 </Database>

 <Services>
    <Wash>1</Wash>
    // add all lines below to config.xmlxml
    <Greeter>0</Greeter>
 </Services>

 <Options>
    <TaxRate>8.125</TaxRate>
    <AskForZipcode>0</AskForZipcode>
    // add all lines below to config.xml
    <AutoSave>1</AutoSave>
 </Options>
</config>
```

By the way, the proper way of commenting in xml is the same as html, which is `<!--comment-->`

Comment: When you say that I need to know the tag I want to import can you give me a example. Not sure what you mean xml is all new to me Thanks

Comment: Ok that fine but in the end it is just combining the two xml files. I need it to create one that will take the extra lines in the template and add them to the original one kind like a update. My Goal is to have a finish product of the two together without change the original value of the first lines in the config. I really hope I am explaining my self correctly lol

Comment: In a well form xml file, all information are in tags. When you say 'line', it wouldn't just be plain text, it will be text inside tag. Each tag can be consider a 'node'. Think of your xml document as a tree, a root note will have some children, and some childeran will have more children. You will need to know the name of a child (which is tag name) in order to import the child to another xml.

Comment: Refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.importnode.aspx for details about ImportNode.

Comment: If you have trouble putting that in code, try writing out pseudocode one paper, walk through the iteration by hand, and see if your pseudocode is doing what you desired. Then put your pseudocode in actual C# code and debug from there.

Comment: Yea I ran that example and I end up with two <book> tags. I was looking for something that would insert the new lines to the original file. btw thank you for your time.

Comment: right, you will need to know the tag name. In the MS example, the tag name is 'book'. In your example, the tag names are DatabaseName, Greeter, and AutoSave right? Get those 'node' by using their tag name, and import those 'node' to config.xml